# Cannot access a more expensive branded fare when lower price branded fare is unavailable when using Amadeus flight search

Tags: amadeus

i am using the self service portal Amadeus flight search API. I have had great success with it but have hit a hurdle. As shown below, United offer basic economy, and united economy in the ECONOMY cabin. when searching through the flight offer search api, it returns the lowest branded fare possible (basic economy), which can then be inputted into the branded fare upselling api to access the united economy details. However, when the basic economy is sold out, it does not return the united economy instead. Thus, I cannot access the united economy flight details.

Surely this is user error. How can I access the united economy flight details for this flight. These are the search parameters I used.

```
params =     {
        "currencyCode": "USD",
        "originDestinations": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "originLocationCode": "EWR",
                "destinationLocationCode": "SBP",
                "departureDateTimeRange": {
                    "date": "2023-10-12"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "originLocationCode": "SBP",
                "destinationLocationCode": "EWR",
                "departureDateTimeRange": {
                    "date": "2023-10-21"
                }
            }
        ],
        "travelers": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "travelerType": "ADULT"
            }
        ],
        "sources": ["GDS"],
        "searchCriteria": {
                        "additionalInformation": {
                            "brandedFares": True
                        },
                        "allowAlternativeFareOptions": True,
        
            "flightFilters": {
                "carrierRestrictions": {
                    "includedCarrierCodes": ["UA"]
                },
                "cabinRestrictions": [
                            {
                                "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                                "coverage": "MOST_SEGMENTS",
                                "originDestinationIds": ["1"]
                            },
                            {
                                "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                                "coverage": "MOST_SEGMENTS",
                                "originDestinationIds": ["2"]
                            }
                ]
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Flight Offer Search API is designed to return the cheapest available flights so yes, if the offer is not available, you won't see the result and you won't be using it to call branded fares upsell API.

In your scenario, you may need to search the flight schedules which is not available in Amadeus Self-Service APIs.

The more advanced flight search capabilities are available in [Enterprise APIs](https://developers.amadeus.com/enterprise/category/air/api/search-and-shopping?catalogId=2).